# On a Linux shell, what is echo $1 supposed to do?

Tags: unix, shell, echo

I do a `echo $1`, it prints out what is the default login shell used.

But for `echo $2` onwards, all I get is a newline. Why is that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

$1 (or $2,$3 ...) is supposed to be the arguments given to some script.

Here's an example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "\$1 is now $1"
echo "\$2 is now $2"
echo "\$3 is now $3"
```

And the example output

```
jaba@lappy:/tmp$ ./example.sh 
$1 is now 
$2 is now 
$3 is now 
jaba@lappy:/tmp$ ./example.sh 1 2 3
$1 is now 1
$2 is now 2
$3 is now 3
```

Comment: And $0 is the name of the scipt being executed, analogous to argv.

Answer (score 4):

> **$1** is the argument passed for shell script.

Suppose, you run

```
./myscript.sh hello 123
```

then

> **$1** will be **hello**
>
> **$2** will be **123**

Answer (score 3):

In your case $1 prints default login shell used because this argument was passed to script that runs your login shell. 
But if you'll write and run your own script in current session, $1, $2, ... will be parameters that you send to your script.